Well-defined metric on AdS boundary
I'm reading Lecture Notes on Holographic Renormalization, particularly section 3 on asymptotically anti-de Sitter spacetimes. I will summarize a part of the discussion.
The AdS metric in conformal coordinates is given by,
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}
ds^2 = \frac{\ell^2}{\cos^2 \theta} (-dt^2 + d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\Omega^2_{d-1})
\end{equation}
where $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. The metric has a second order pole at $\theta = \pi/2$ where the boundary is located. Due to this pole, the bulk metric does not yield a metric at the boundary. It yields a conformal structure instead.
Consider a “defining function” function $r(x)$ that is positive in the interior $X$ of AdS, but has a first order pole at the boundary $M$. We now multiply the AdS metric by $r^2$ and evaluate it at the boundary,
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{2}
g_{(0)} = r^2 G|_{\pi/2}
\end{equation}
where $G$ is the bulk metric. One possible choice for the defining function is $r = \cos \theta$. Generally, we will call a metric $G$ conformally compact if it has a second order pole at the boundary $M$ but there exists a defining function such that,
\begin{equation}\tag{3}\label{3}
g = r^2 G \qquad \text{where} \;\;\; g|_M = g_{(0)}
\end{equation}
This procedure defines a conformal structure on $M$. There is another quantity that smoothly extends to $M$ that is independent of choices (depends only on the conformal structure),
\begin{equation}\tag{4}\label{4}
|dr|^2_g = g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu r \partial_\nu r
\end{equation}
This can be shown using eq.(\ref{3}). The curvature of the bulk metric $G$ is,
\begin{equation}\tag{5}\label{5}
R_{\kappa \lambda \mu \nu}[G] = |dr|^2_g (G_{\kappa \mu} G_{\nu \lambda} - G_{\mu \lambda} G_{\nu \kappa}) + \mathcal{O}(r^{-3})
\end{equation}

Eq.(\ref{4}) looks like an inner product but what does it mean, and how to derive it from eq.(\ref{3})?
The bulk metric $G$ is given by eq.(\ref{1}). Although eq.(\ref{4}) is independent of choices, let's use
\begin{equation}\tag{6}\label{6}
r=\cos \theta, \qquad dr = -\sin \theta d\theta = \sqrt{1-r^2} d\theta
\end{equation}
for intuition so the bulk metric $G$ and the metric $g$ will be,
\begin{equation}\tag{7}\label{7}
ds^2_G = \frac{\ell^2}{r^2} \left(-dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1-r^2} + (1-r^2) d\Omega^2_{d-1} \right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{8}\label{8}
ds^2_g = \ell^2 \left(-dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1-r^2} + (1-r^2) d\Omega^2_{d-1} \right)
\end{equation}
If we consider the vector $d\vec{r}$ then,
\begin{equation}
d\vec{r} = \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x^\mu} dx^\mu \quad \rightarrow \quad d\vec{r} \cdot d\vec{r} = \partial_\mu \vec{r} \partial_\nu \vec{r} dx^\mu dx^\nu
\end{equation}
For $|d\vec{r} \cdot d\vec{r}|_G$, we have $G_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu \vec{r} \partial_\nu \vec{r} = \frac{1}{r^2 (1-r^2)}$, while for $|d\vec{r} \cdot d\vec{r}|_g$ we have $g_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu \vec{r} \partial_\nu \vec{r} = \frac{1}{1-r^2}$. I'm not sure how to connect this to the derivation.
In addition, how does $|dr|^2_g$ appear in the curvature eq.(\ref{5}) of the bulk metric $G$?
